# What is the difference between href and toString when converting an URL interface to string?

Tags: javascript, url

Let's say I use the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL) to create a new URL. E.g. like that:

```
new URL('https://www.example.com/démonstration.html?query=6#bla')
```

Now I need this as a plain string. **How do I best convert it?**

**Note:** The examples here are minimal examples. I obviously don't convert a (hardcoded) string to an URL object and back to a string. To give some context, imagine I modify the URL object in between (possibly with user input) and/or pass it to different functions or so. In the end, I have an URL object and want it as a plain string.

---

I've found the following ways:

- via `href` property:

  ```
  (new URL('https://www.example.com/démonstration.html?query=6#bla')).href
  // "https://www.example.com/d%C3%A9monstration.html?query=6#bla"
  ```
- via `toString` method:

  ```
  (new URL('https://www.example.com/démonstration.html?query=6#bla')).toString()
  // "https://www.example.com/d%C3%A9monstration.html?query=6#bla"
  ```

As you can see, in my example, it returns exactly the same.

---

So looking [at the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Properties) you notice:

- `href` is "a USVString containing the whole URL."
- `toString` returns "a USVString containing the whole URL. It is a synonym for URL.href, though it can't be used to modify the value."

Okay, I don't want to modify it.
But are there really no differences? Maybe regarding performance, browser support¹ or even code style?
I have to decide for one, so which one should I choose?

¹ Actually [I can see there are differences in the compatibility table for these conversion ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility). So I guess there are also some legacy implementations that handle things differently or so. I cannot believe these are true "synonym" and this gab in browser support seems to support that believe.

Comment: Why don't you have the url as a string `const url = 'http://www.example.com/démonstration.html?query=6#bla'` and then use that when creating the url object `new URL(url)`. Then you have both.

Comment: @Andy My code was a minimal example. Obviously, I don't convert it from and to this object for fun and not in an one-liner as demonstrated above. Image a bigger subject here where URL objects are used for passing URLs as APIs or modifying them etc. and finally you just want a string URL at some point. (**Edit:** Now added this note to the question.)

Comment: You'd be surprised the obvious things people miss in their code on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#URL-stringification-behavior), they are doing exactly the same. The `href` attribute is marked up as a [`stringifier`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-stringifiers), which means that [in JavaScript](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-stringifier) the class gets a `toString` method with exactly the same behaviour as the attribute.

As you have noticed, browser support is not the same for them. Also one is more to type and transmit than the other. This comes down entirely to preference. However, personally I find that an explicit `toString` call best conveys the message "*I have an URL object and want it as a plain string.*"

Comment: The [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/url-href-vs-tostring) shows near similar numbers.

Comment: @KoshVery Maybe one should not always re-create the URL object on each test run(?). At least [I get a different result](https://hostux.pics/images/2019/01/26/grafik6449526984759584.png), [in this case](https://jsperf.com/url-href-vs-tostring/2).

Comment: @rugk [All microbenchmarks are bound to fail…](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html)